# Unable to Update the Records in the Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update values from one table to another. SQL Server is showing 1 row(s) affected. But records do not get updated.

This is the Merge update I am using:

```
MERGE dbo.Patients p 
USING #Patient_Already_in_System s
ON p.PatientID = s.PatientID
WHEN MATCHED AND s.Student_ID = 165364
THEN UPDATE 
SET  FirstName = CAST(SUBSTRING(s.Client_First_Name,1,25) AS VARCHAR(25))
    ,LastName = CAST(SUBSTRING(s.Client_Last_Name,1,35) AS VARCHAR(35))
    ,MiddleName = CAST(s.Student_ID AS VARCHAR(25))
    ,Street = CAST(s.Address AS VARCHAR(100))
    ,StateID = CAST(s.State AS CHAR(2))
    ,ZipCode = CAST(s.Zip AS varchar(10))
    ,Gender = ( SELECT id FROM dbo.lkpGenderIdentityExym WHERE id = s.gender)
    ,DOB = CAST(s.DOB AS DATETIME)
    ,Hispanic = CASE WHEN s.Ethnicity2 = 'No, not Hispanic or Latino' THEN CAST(0 AS BIT)
                     WHEN s.Ethnicity2 = 'Yes, Hispanic or Latino' THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
                     ELSE NULL
                 END
    ,GradeLevel = CAST(s.grade AS VARCHAR(25))
    ,RaceID = (SELECT ID FROM dbo.lkpRace WHERE DMHDescriptionForCSIRace = s.race)
    ,Location = (SELECT id FROM dbo.Locations WHERE Description LIKE s.Location OR Description LIKE s.Location + ' High')
    ,AssignedToID = CASE WHEN (SELECT id FROM dbo.lkpUsers WHERE FullName = s.Primary_Therapist)  IS NULL THEN 809 -- Z-EXYM-Malik Qayyum
     ELSE (SELECT id FROM dbo.lkpUsers WHERE FullName = s.Primary_Therapist) 
     END;
```

I have also tried a regular UPDATE Table Set ..... Same thing. Any pointers on what I am missing?

Comment: Try SET NOCOUNT ON or check the @@ROWCOUNT immediately after executing.  Is it zero or something else?  If it's zero, then that almost certainly means that your conditions are never getting matched, otherwise it could be something else (like triggers interfering, or you not connected to the database that you think you are, etc.).

Comment: "1 row affected" might also be caused by the execution plan, or by a trigger.

Comment: We need a [MRE] in order to assist. Debugging merge statements is somewhat tricky.

Comment: Add an `output` statement to check the ID of the row updated or not.

Comment: Are the source values for `Student_ID=163564` actually different? You can still update a row without changing any of its values.

Comment: The temporary table was not up to date, hence the condition was never met. Dropping and re-creating the temporary table solved the issue.

Comment: The '(x) rows affected' was shown due to a trigger. We have an Audit table maintained which tracks the changes on the update. It was triggering each time I have executed the merge/update statement.